# Beamer, \column, pspicture: is this a bug, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: beamer, pstricks, columns

Here are my two examples, both don't render correctly: the position of the text relative to the pspicture is wrong in both versions. [Edit:] More precisely, the text and the picture <strike>are supposed to</strike>  have their top edges aligned, but they are not. [Edit:] The preceding sentence from the original is wrong, see the answer for explanation. The error grows bigger in a non-minimized example.

This is a minimized example, in my actual use case this causes me big trouble (been banging head against wall for 2+hours):

Compiling with 
pdflatex --shell-escape

Example1:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage {auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.25\textwidth}%try inserting a blank line immediately after this comment
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)%
\psline(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
\psline(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
\end{pspicture}
\column{0.75\textwidth}
$1+1=2$
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Example2: (same as above, only one extra line has been added):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage {auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.25\textwidth}%try inserting a blank line immediately after this comment

\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)%
\psline(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
\psline(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
\end{pspicture}
\column{0.75\textwidth}
$1+1=2$
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The end results in the order Example1, Example2 are attached. What is going on?

Example1:

[image]

Example2:

[image]

Comment: Try with `\begin{columns}[T]`.

Comment: Works like a charm, many thanks! Out of curiosity, what is going on?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Please make that an answer [with explanation :-)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug.

You may use `\begin{columns}[T]` instead of `\begin{columns}[t]`.

> `T` is similar to the `t` option, but `T` aligns the tops of the first lines while `t` aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. ([*p.125, beameruserguide*](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=125))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage {auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[T]
\column{0.25\textwidth}%try inserting a blank line immediately after this comment
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)%
\psline(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
\psline(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
\end{pspicture}
\column{0.75\textwidth}
$1+1=2$
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps note also that this applies to all boxes, not just `pspicture` (I'd use a `\rule` to show this).

Comment: You are right, It is not a PSTricks problem!

Answer (score 1):

The `pspicture` environment is a TeX box on the current baseline. In your example the box is 2.4cm wide and 2.4cm high. It's *internal* origin (on PostScript level) is 1.2cm from the left and 1.2cm from the bottom of the TeX box. Compare:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks,calc}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\fboxsep=0pt
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \fbox{\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
            \psline{->}(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
            \psline{->}(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
            \end{pspicture}}
        \column{0.75\textwidth}
        $1+1=2$
    \end{columns}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \fbox{\begin{pspicture}[shift=*](-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
            \psline{->}(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
            \psline{->}(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
            \end{pspicture}}
        \column{0.75\textwidth}
        $1+1=2$
    \end{columns}

  \setbox1=\hbox{1}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
            \fbox{\begin{pspicture}[shift=\dimexpr-2.4cm+\ht1](-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
            \psline{->}(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
            \psline{->}(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
            \end{pspicture}}
        \column{0.75\textwidth}
            $1+1=2$
    \end{columns}

\framebreak
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \column{0.25\textwidth}
        \fbox{\begin{pspicture}[shift=-2.4cm](-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
            \psline{->}(-1.2,0)(1.2,0)
            \psline{->}(0,-1.2)(0,1.2)
            \end{pspicture}}
        \column{0.75\textwidth}
        $1+1=2$
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]